# How to add ArcGIS ONLINE map to qgis?

Tags: arcgis, qgis

How do I add this map

https://mestosnv.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=cf67cbfe70f243928113e131b9f051b8

to QGIS as a layer or how can I download data from this map to use in qgis?

I haven't found the relevant services anywhere

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0f52d535b8e848de91f523f37cc7f68f

I found some map services from this user but this map with layer is not there
https://services8.arcgis.com/z9muuypGqZUVpznM/ArcGIS/rest/services